# Ordered execution in akka

Tags: java, akka

I have a need to create an application that needs to process product updates.  For a given product the updates *must* be processed in order but updates for different products are independent and are thus can be processed in parallel.  Furthermore for a given product the update must be completely processed before proceeding of the next update for that product can begin.

In straight Java the solution to this seems fairly straightforward (just create some ordered executor that maintains a queue of tasks per product and submit tasks to that) but I was wondering if this is possible in akka.  From reading the docs it looks like it might be by using a custom router and a pinned dispatcher but I'm struggling to see exactly how it would work.

Comment: Sounds for me like a use-case for Event sourcing. Are there any limitations that you didn't mention that would prevent you from implementing an actor per product?

Comment: Thanks for the response- I think the large number of products (> 100K) might make having an actor per product unfeasible although probably this could be mitigated by splitting the products into segments and then having an actor per product segment.

Comment: 109k actors shouldn't be a problem if they're otherwise lightweight.

Comment: I think there are examples of millions of actors being spawned. you can always try to somehow `put to sleep` those actors that are inactive for longer than X period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a separate actor for each product. This is a perfect use case for Akka actors. Updates would be represented by messages sent to the product actors.

1) "For a given product the updates must be processed in order"
Done. Messages (updates) in the actor's mailbox are processed in  order.

2) "updates for different products are independent and are thus can be processed in parallel"
Done. Separate products are represented by separate actors - they can work in parallel.

3) "for a given product the update must be completely processed before proceeding of the next update for that product can begin"
Done. One actor does not process more messages at once.

4) "the large number of products (> 100K) might make having an actor per product unfeasible"
No problem. Actors are very lightweight, they don't block threads. You can have millions of actors.

5) "this could be mitigated by splitting the products into segments and then having an actor per product segment"
Yes, that would work too.